# .NET Core console app Dependency Injection setup

Tags: c#, .net-core, console

How can I add more servicies to DI? as for now only ConvertService is DI when i was trying to add another one for example

```
services.AddTransient<Authorization>();
```

it has not effect and i cannot DI Authorization service to other classes. How to handle if i want to add more servicies to be added to DI. Also i can only inject `IHttpCLient` to `ConvertService`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProtocolConvert
{
    class Program
    {
       private static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()

            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHttpClient("GitHub", httpClient =>
                     {
                         httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("tokenUrl").Value);
                         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
                              "X-API-ID", Configuration.GetSection("X-API-ID").Value);
                         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
                             "X-API-SECRET", Configuration.GetSection("X-API-SECRET").Value);
                     });
                   
                    services.AddTransient<ConvertService>();
                 
                }).Build();

            var svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ConvertService>(host.Services);
          
            await svc.ConvertToCsv();
        }
       


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not pretty sure of the purpose of your implementation. But I think you should use `GetService<ConvertService>()` instead of create a new instance of your service class.

You can see an example here https://siderite.dev/blog/creating-console-app-with-dependency-injection-in-/

I hope this helps you.